# Zoom freezes on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: 20.04, video, freeze

So, I installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on a new Lenovo E 15 Thinkpad and I'm experiencing issues with Zoom. Every time I join a new meeting the video freezes after some time (usually a couple of minutes). I can still hear other conference participants, but my video remains frozen and I have to restart Zoom (until it freezes again after some time). So basically, I am not able to use Zoom on my computer.
There have been no other video-related problems until now. I have been using other video conferencing tools only in the browser though. (Using Zoom via the browser is not an option btw.)

System information:

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
*-display                 
       Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
       Produkt: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       Hersteller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:04:00.0
       Logischer Name: /dev/fb0
       Version: c1
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       Konfiguration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       Ressourcen: iomemory:40-3f iomemory:40-3f irq:42 memory:460000000-46fffffff memory:470000000-4701fffff ioport:1000(Größe=256) memory:fd300000-fd37ffff

OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.0.3
```

Any help would be really appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and same symptoms. Please share if you managed to solve it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't solved the problem yet. Zoom-Support wasn't helpful and my best guess right now is that the problem is related to the Linux kernel. Downgrade to a lower Ubuntu version might be an option but not sure about that. Still: Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I created a ticket with zoom support. They advised using [5.8.6.379](https://zoom.us/client/5.8.6.739/zoom_amd64.deb) as a temporary workaround. This version is not available through snap but can be installed through `.deb`.

I've tried it and this version works without issue.

I'll update here if they notify once they've solved the issue.

**Edit**:

I was updated by support. **Zoom released a new version named 5.10.3 that fixes the issue**. I tried it out and it works for me.

Comment: The solution provided by twitu works with my configuration (using Zoom version 5.8.6.379). Thanks for sharing!

Comment: zoom 5.10.4 is giving me this issue.  where do i get 5.10.3?

Answer (score 0):

5.10.3 link https://zoom.us/client/5.10.32278/zoom_amd64.deb

But can confirm that 5.10.7 works

Comment: That link isn’t working

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1231092)